# Facing error for importing _String from Data.Aeson.Lens

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_String,key)
postRetweet1 tweetId = do
    tweetId >>= \tweetId1 -> (CM.foldM (\arr tid ->  ((try (postWith authenticate (retweetUrl++tid++".json") (DB.pack "ABC")) ):: IO (Either SomeException (Response BL.ByteString)) ) >>= 
         \sc ->
                case sc of
                    Right val ->   if (val ^. responseStatus ^. statusCode)==200
                                        then pure (arr++[val ^. responseBody . key "text" . _String ])  
                                    else pure (arr)     


                Left x -> pure (arr) ) [] tweetId1 )
```

this is the error im getting

```
Module ‘Data.Aeson.Lens’ does not export ‘_String’
```

i had referred this http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/tutorial.html

Comment: You import `_String`, but never use it, so, you can probably drop it. I think you are following an outdated manual, since `_String` does not seem to be part of the `Data.Aeson.Lens` module (anymore).

Comment: You're probably using the [`aeson-lens` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-lens-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html) instead of the [`lens-aeson` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html).

Comment: Hayoo (or Stackage Hoogle) can help clarifying situations like this. Here is a [Hayoo query](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=_String) that shows the `_String` you are looking for belongs to the *lens-aeson* package, as @4castle points out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use lens-aeson package for `_String`

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html